# Oracle date to_char group and order by

Tags: mysql, oracle

I am working to migrate my queries from mysql to oracle. In mysql I am using query to get only month

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(IDATEIN, '%M-%Y') as MY 
  FROM ATTENDANCE 
 GROUP BY MY 
 ORDER BY IDATEIN DESC
```

which giving me results like

```
MYDATE
DEC-2016
NOV-2016
OCT-2016
```

My table contains

```
IDATEIN
2016-12-01
2016-12-01
2016-12-01
2016-10-01
2016-11-01
```

In oracle I am trying to use this

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(DATEIN, 'MON-YYYY') AS MY 
    FROM HRM_ATTENDANCE 
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(DATEIN, 'MON-YYYY') 
   ORDER BY TO_CHAR(DATEIN, 'MON-YYYY')
```

But it ordering to abphables, like

```
 APR-2016
 APR-2017
 AUG-2016
 FEB-2016
 FEB-2017
```

Please help

Oracle Result

[image: Oracle Result]

Mysql Result

[image: Mysql Result]

Comment: What is an `abphables` ?

Comment: Where are the 2017 entries in your mysql result?

Comment: Show us the result for both queries with the same Input records

Comment: Ok I am showing both results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TRUNC` to truncate the date to the start of the month and `GROUP BY`/`ORDER BY` that date value and just covert it to a string in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT   TO_CHAR( TRUNC( DATEIN, 'MM' ), 'MON-YYYY') AS MY 
FROM     HRM_ATTENDANCE 
GROUP BY TRUNC( DATEIN, 'MM' ) 
ORDER BY TRUNC( DATEIN, 'MM' )
```

However, since your data appears to only be for the first of the month then this can be simplified to:

```
SELECT   TO_CHAR( DATEIN, 'MON-YYYY') AS MY 
FROM     HRM_ATTENDANCE 
GROUP BY DATEIN 
ORDER BY DATEIN
```